# Polling File Consumer In Apache

Tags: java, architecture, apache-camel

I have started playing around with Apache camel recently. So being the experimental type I thought I would create a simple project that would scan a file directory every couple of seconds to see if I have a new file pick that file up and then copy it to another folder. Later on I want to place these files into a database.

So keeping with the basics first I created a route such as the following:

```
 from("file://c:/CTest/inbox?noop=true")
                .to("file://C:/Ctest/outbox");
```

This worked and I thought ok lets add a timer. Initially I made the mistake of using a timer and trying this:

```
from("timer://myTimer?period=50").to("file://c:/CTest/inbox?noop=true")
                .to("file://C:/Ctest/outbox");
```

I then had some strange exception about not being able to write a file. I then realised by placing the file route after the timer route it became a producer. So I researched a bit and here is where I am little confused.

So from my understanding the file component uses the scheduled poll pattern. There is even a pollStrategy option in the file route url pattern. There is also a Polling Consumer EIP.

So here is where my confusion sets in.

1) If the file component uses the scheduled poll pattern does it use/implement the polling conumser EIP?

2) How do I add a simple schedule to the file component to consume files say every 30 seconds?

3) How do I create my own pollingStrategy by implementing org.apache.camel.PollingConsumerPollStrategy?

I suspect I can do something like this:

```
    from("file://c:/CTest/inbox?noop=true&pollStrategy=some-expression")
                .to("file://C:/Ctest/outbox");
```

I have tried to get some examples around this but I am either not looking at the right places or missing the plot completely. I guess this is not so much a code related question but more of a what is the best strategy/pattern for this approach.

Thanks
Namphibian

Comment: Could you please guide how you used the from() API ? I'm not sure what configuration needs to be done and how ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Camel offers a feature called routepolicy
http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html

It allows you to associate policies to routes. We provide a number of policies out of the box. A policy can be any kind of logic. For example we offer a throttling policy, which on-the-fly suspend/resume routes based on threadsholds.

Another out the box policy is a scheduled policy, so you can specify 'opening hours' for a route. So you can use that as well. But mind its for opening hours, so you specify a start/end time. There is a quartz cron based policy http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html so you can configure this to start the route on monday, and let it run for a little while.

If you need to stop a route from within a route, then thats a bit more complicated, there is a FAQ about this here: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html

Comment: Thanks Claus. Seems like I still have a long way to go. So is it possible to start up a Camel route from a timer or quartz component?  Right so I guess there is no right answer but when would you use a poll strategy, when would you use a route policy, when would you use a delay? Your thoughts and experience on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your needs. The pollEnrich can only pickup a single file at a time, so it has its limitations, if your use-case is to pickup and process all files from a directory. If so then the route policy makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) If the file component uses the scheduled poll pattern does it
>   use/implement the polling conumser EIP?

Yes, the file producer implements the [ScheduledPollEndpoint](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/ScheduledPollEndpoint.html). From the [doc](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html):

> Quite a few inbound Camel endpoints use a scheduled poll pattern to
>   receive messages and push them through the Camel processing routes.
>   That is to say externally from the client the endpoint appears to use
>   an Event Driven Consumer but internally a scheduled poll is used to
>   monitor some kind of state or resource and then fire message
>   exchanges. Since this a such a common pattern, polling components can
>   extend the ScheduledPollConsumer base class which makes it simpler to
>   implement this pattern.
>
> 2) How do I add a simple schedule to the file component to consume
>   files sa every 30 seconds?

Using the `delay` option:

```
from("file://c:/CTest/inbox?noop=true&delay=30000").to("file://C:/Ctest/outbox");
```

3) How do I create my own pollingStrategy by implementing org.apache.camel.PollingConsumerPollStrategy?

Have a look at the source code: [DefaultPollingConsumerPollStrategy](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultPollingConsumerPollStrategy.java) or [LimitedPollingConsumerPollStrategy](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/LimitedPollingConsumerPollStrategy.java).

You use a custom pollStrategy like this:

```
from("file://inbox/?pollStrategy=#myPoll").to(...)
```

Where #myPoll i defined in the [registry](http://camel.apache.org/registry.html) more info at the bottom of [this](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) page.

Comment: Hi ebaxt. Ok so I dont have to implement a polling strategy if I just wanted to poll every 30 seconds say? I achieve this by using the delay option(makes sense note to self try read a little more). Then for more complex scenario I would define a bean and use it to definee say a schedule that for example polls every monday at 11:30 am?

Comment: I just used the delay and it works like a charm. I cant believe it is that easy. Camel ROCKS!. Question answered I will research the custom Polling Strategy a bit more! Thanks.

Comment: If you need more control over the polling schedule, you can use the quartz component and use pollEnrich like so: `from("quartXXXX").pollEnrich("file://xx").to(...);`

Comment: Mind that pollEnrich will only poll one file at a time. So if you need to poll all files from a directory, then its maybe easier to use the scheduled route policy I talk about below.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Nice, that's very helpful!

Comment: Delay causing only one time delay of specified seconds not every time, please help me in implementing the delay of EVERY 30 s in polling